# Retrieving data using ODATA with javascript

Tags: javascript, odata, crm

I'm trying to return a result set from crm using odata. i'm new to this.. i want to have an asp.net page displaying the values in a datagrid. i'm getting the error odata execution error popup. if i put in the correct server and query string it always fails though.. any suggestions on how to get this work properly

```
    function ExecuteQuery(ODataQuery) {

    //var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
    var serverUrl = "https://server.server.com"; //would be the real server

    // Adjust URL for differences between on premise and online 
//    if (serverUrl.match(/\/$/)) {
   //     serverUrl = serverUrl.substring(0, serverUrl.length - 1);
  //  }


    alert("test");
    var ODataURL = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc" + ODataQuery;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: ODataURL,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            //
            // Handle result from successful execution
            alert("success");
            //data.d.results


        },
        error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorObject) {
            //
            // Handle result from unsuccessful execution
            //


            alert("OData Execution Error Occurred");
        }
    });
}


      <script type="text/javascript">
         ExecuteQuery("the query would go in here);
      </script>
```

Comment: 1. datatype should be dataType. 2. So what is the problem? Any error messages? etc

Comment: the problem is , its not connecting to the site and i'm getting an error "odata execution error"

Comment: Could you change "alert("OData Execution Error Occurred");" to "alert(errorObject);" and attach the error messages thrown?

Comment: ya i could but nothing shows